# Missing textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, texturing

i tried a lot of different methods and before it always worked! But last time I watched a tutorial on how to import a Minecraft world into it. Everything was working but when I wanted to see how it looks if it's rendered I get pink textures. And I can't see how to fix it. Now even with the old rigs, i used it won't work anymore. Could you guys help me?

Comment: You can go to File > External Data > Find Missing Files and search for the files

Answer (score 1):

That simply means the image textures have not been loaded/are not present in the location they were supposed to be in. Just click the folder icons on your image textures and reload each texture.

Comment: Thanks but i already tried alot of things and this aswell it just wont work.

Comment: I don't know what problem this could be then. Try explaining the problem in better detail.

Comment: Do you have skype? Maybe you could help me by screensharing